# How do I set compatible devices to only AVCaptureMultiCamSession compatible devices in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect, multi-camera-api

How can I make sure my app on iOS AppStore only show compatibility for AVCaptureMultiCamSession enabled devices only?
I need to write a key under "Required Device Capabilities" in the info.plist file, but which key?
I didn't find the key in the documentation

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW3

Answer (score 0):

iphone-ipad-minimum-performance-a12 Key worked well

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/uirequireddevicecapabilities